# array to dictionary

Tags: c#, lambda

I'm trying to get this `_valueAdds = List<ValueAddedItemHelper>` into `gridItems` (`Dictionary`) with `_valueAdds`  being the Key and all the values being `false`. But I'm not sure how to do this with Lamda. This how far I got below. I did succeed in doing it with a while loop but would like learn to do it with Lamda

```
gridItems = new Dictionary<ValueAddedItemHelper, bool>();
gridItems = _valueAdds.Select(k => new { k }).ToArray().ToDictionary(t => t, false);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
_valueAdds.ToDictionary(t => t, t => false);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a lambda expression as the second argument (or create the delegate some other way, but a lambda expression will be simplest). Note that the call to `ToArray` isn't required, and nor is the empty dictionary you're creating to start with. Just use:

```
gridItems = _valueAdds.Select(k => new { k })
                      .ToDictionary(t => t, t => false);
```

It's not clear to me why you're using an anonymous type here though... in particular, that *won't* be a `ValueAddedItemHelper`. Do you need the projection at all? Perhaps just:

```
gridItems = _valueAdds.ToDictionary(t => t, t => false);
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I clearly over complicated things for myself.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a ToArray().ToDictionary(). You can simply do a ToDictionary(). And you don't need the first line. The second line will create and fill the dictionary.

The code:

```
gridItems = _valueAdds.ToDictionary(p => p, p => false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `_valueAdds` is an `IEnumerable<ValueAddedItemHelper>` you could do this:

```
gridItems = _valueAdds.ToDictionary(x => x, x => false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
var gridItems = _valueAdds.ToDictionary(k=>k,i=>false);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Select(k => new { k })` is the problem; that creates an anonymous type with a property called `k`.  Just:

```
var gridItems = _valueAdds.ToDictionary(t => t, t => false);
```